# Python on Chrome OS through Linux: Cannot Export DataFrame

Tags: linux, csv, export, google-chrome-os

I'm running a Jupiter Notebook on Google Chrome, and my computer is a Chromebook on which I've installed Linux.

The Notebook runs fine, no problem.

However, when I try to export my pandas DataFrame to my Linux files using this command:

```
DataFrame.to_csv('/mnt/chromeos/DataFrame.csv')
```

I get the following error message:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/chromeos/DataFrame.csv'
```

Does  anyone know why i'm getting this erros message? What can I do  for the permission to be accepted?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit:

I tried the following command:
ls -ld /mnt/chromeos and mount | fgrep chromeos

I get the following output:
ls: cannot access 'and': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'mount': No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 80 Dec  8 16:41 /mnt/chromeos/

Comment: What is `/mnt/chromeos`? What did you mount there? What are the permissions of `/mnt/chromeos`? Please [edit] your question and show the output of `ls -ld /mnt/chromeos` and `mount | fgrep chromeos`. Copy&paste the command and the corresponding output as text and format it as a code block.

Comment: I've managed to save the file in:  DataFrame.to_csv('/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads/DataFrame.csv')

Comment: `ls -ld /mnt/chromeos` and `mount | fgrep chromeos` These are two separate commands as you should be able to see from the formatting. The word *and*  does not belong to the command. Please run the commands separately and format each command and its corresponding output as a code block similar to the existing code blocks, e.g. by adding a line `~~~` before and after it.